# Can't use logical on a specific DataMatrix

Tags: matlab

I can't wrap my head around this problem and I've been sitting with it all morning.
I need to log2 transform all elements of a DataMatrix and then use a logical vector to extract a subset. Here's the issue:

```
>> get(dataSet2) %Error prone
        Name: ''
    RowNames: {195x1 cell}
    ColNames: {1x22283 cell}
       NRows: 195
       NCols: 22283
       NDims: 2
ElementClass: 'double'

A = log2(dataSet2);
>> get(A)
        Name: ''
    RowNames: {195x1 cell}
    ColNames: {1x22283 cell}
       NRows: 195
       NCols: 22283
       NDims: 2
ElementClass: 'double'

>> A(outputVector2, :)
Error using message
In 'bioinfo:DataMatrix:subsref:UnrecognizedRowName', parameter {1} must be a scalar.

Error in bioma.data.DataMatrix/subsref (line 61)
            error(message('bioinfo:DataMatrix:subsref:UnrecognizedRowName',
            commaSeparatedList( rowSubNames( rowIndices==0 ) )))
```

Here's another attempt:

```
>> B=dmarrayfun(@log2, dataSet2);
Error using bioma.data.DataMatrix>createDataMatrix (line 207)
The argument MATRIX must be a 2-dimensional numeric or logical array.

Error in bioma.data.DataMatrix (line 187)
        obj = createDataMatrix(obj, varargin{:});

Error in bioma.data.DataMatrix/dmarrayfun (line 138)
     b = bioma.data.DataMatrix(bMatrix, rowNames,colNames);
```

Looking at log2 by using dmarrayfun it outputs complex numbers, i.e. 3.5 + 0.0i.
The weirdest part is of course that it works perfectly on my other DataMatrix:

```
>> get(dataSet) %Functional
        Name: ''
    RowNames: {264x1 cell}
    ColNames: {1x22283 cell}
       NRows: 264
       NCols: 22283
       NDims: 2
ElementClass: 'double'
```

There's probably some simple conversion or whatever I'm missing. Any ideas on what I could do would really help a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution sigh.

Applying @real to the entire DataMatrix solved it.
It still doesn't explain why log2 just magically decided to use complex numbers though.

Comment: So what exactly did you take the `log2` of that resulted in a complex value?

Comment: That's what was truly weird. The data was just a lot of normal double values (2.5634, 7.324 etc). I had another DataMatrix with very similar data, but on it log2 functioned like normal.